# TEqualityComparer<T> may fail for records due to alignment

Tags: delphi, hash

We recently had an issue with a `TDictionary<T>` instance that failed to lookup items correctly that are were already included in the dictionary. The problem occurred only in 64Bit builds. I was able to break the problem down to this code:

```
var
  i1, i2: TPair<Int64,Integer>;
begin
  FillMemory(@i1, sizeof(i1), $00);
  FillMemory(@i2, sizeof(i1), $01);
  i1.Key := 2;
  i1.Value := -1;
  i2.Key := i1.Key;
  i2.Value := i1.Value;
  Assert(TEqualityComparer<TPair<Int64,Integer>>.Default.Equals(i1, i2));
  Assert(TEqualityComparer<TPair<Int64,Integer>>.Default.GetHashCode(i1) = TEqualityComparer<TPair<Int64,Integer>>.Default.GetHashCode(i2));
end;
```

The assertions fail in Win64 builds. The problem seems to occur due to the record alignment: The size of this TPair is 16 bytes, but only 12 bytes are filled with data. The `TEqualityComparer` however takes all 16 bytes into account. So 2 record values may be treated as not equal, although all members are equal, just because of the different previous content of the memory

Can this be considered as a bug or behavior by design? It is a pitfall in any case. What is the best solution for such situations?

As workaround one may use `NativeInt` instead of `Integer`, however this `Integer` type was not under our control.

Comment: You have to write a bespoke comparer. My view is the defect id that default compares exist for records at all.

Comment: That is why you should use Default(<type>) to initialize records. AFAIK it generates code that also takes care of zeroing out the padding memory.

Comment: @Stefan: Maybe you are right, but this makes records really inconvenient to use, and how TDictionary<T> handles this is beyond my control.

Comment: @Joachim There is no problem with TDictionary. Just initialize TPair (as any other record) properly (use Default function as Stefan suggested) and you will be fine.

Comment: `type TMyPair = TPair<Int64, Integer>; var i1, i2: TMyPair; begin i1 := Default(TMyPair); i2 := Default(TMyPair); ...`

Comment: That advice is bogus. You should not require users to zero out padding bytes. Assigning all the fields is all that should be required. Write a comparer. You will need to anyway as soon as you have, e.g. strings.

Comment: @David You will have to implement custom comparer for every record type and it may lead to issues anyway. One day you extend the record and it will be compiled without questions, but will not work properly because of custom comparer. I do not see how custom comparer is better than one line of initialization in general. But for widely used types (like TPair) it makes sense.

Comment: @Andrei You have to implement custom comparer most of the time anyway. Strings, interfaces etc. Also floating point types. I tend to put my comparer with the type declaration, inside the type, to reduce risk of forgetting to update when extending or modifying. And your approach relies heavily on implementation details.

Comment: @David Me too :) And i have custom analog of TPair because of this. But it depends. For example in our projects we have tons of record types and they do not have any pointer types. In this case creating of custom comparer for every type will be spending time for useless code consuming extra CPU time. For general usage types (TPair etc) it is indeed worth to spend some time and implement comparer compatible with (almost) any type.

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn It's not just records allocated with pointers - even stack allocated records will be filled with garbage in the padding areas so you simply cannot rely on them being hashed or compared properly generally.  In any case where you need to use a record as a key or need to make an equality comparison you really need a bespoke comparer.

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn In complex projects with 3rd party code not every record initialization is under our control. Tho approach of initializing every record with Default is error prone and does not scale well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug. The behaviour is by design. Without inspection or perhaps some compile time support for understanding these types, it is hard to write a general purpose comparer for arbitrary structured types.

The default record comparer can only safely be used on types with no padding and containing only certain simple value types that can be compared using naive binary comparison. For instance, floating point types are out because their comparison operators are more complex. Think of NaNs, negative zero, etc.

I think that the only robust way to deal with this is to write your own equality comparer. Others have suggested default initialising all record instances, but this places a significant burden on consumers of such types, and runs the risk of obscure and hard to track down defects in case some code forgets to default initialise.

I would use `TEqualityComparer<T>.Construct` to create suitable equality comparers. This requires the least amount of boilerplate. You supply two anonymous methods: an equals function and a hash function, and `Construct` returns you a newly minted comparer.

You can wrap this up in a generic class like so:

```
uses
  System.Generics.Defaults,
  System.Generics.Collections;

{$IFOPT Q+}
  {$DEFINE OverflowChecksEnabled}
  {$Q-}
{$ENDIF}
function CombinedHash(const Values: array of Integer): Integer;
var
  Value: Integer;
begin
  Result := 17;
  for Value in Values do begin
    Result := Result*37 + Value;
  end;
end;
{$IFDEF OverflowChecksEnabled}
  {$Q+}
{$ENDIF}

type
  TPairComparer = class abstract
  public
    class function Construct<TKey, TValue>(
      const EqualityComparison: TEqualityComparison<TPair<TKey, TValue>>;
      const Hasher: THasher<TPair<TKey, TValue>>
    ): IEqualityComparer<TPair<TKey, TValue>>; overload; static;
    class function Construct<TKey, TValue>: IEqualityComparer<TPair<TKey, TValue>>; overload; static;
  end;


class function TPairComparer.Construct<TKey, TValue>(
  const EqualityComparison: TEqualityComparison<TPair<TKey, TValue>>;
  const Hasher: THasher<TPair<TKey, TValue>>
): IEqualityComparer<TPair<TKey, TValue>>;
begin
  Result := TEqualityComparer<TPair<TKey, TValue>>.Construct(
    EqualityComparison,
    Hasher
  );
end;

class function TPairComparer.Construct<TKey, TValue>: IEqualityComparer<TPair<TKey, TValue>>;
begin
  Result := Construct<TKey, TValue>(
    function(const Left, Right: TPair<TKey, TValue>): Boolean
    begin
      Result :=
        TEqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(Left.Key, Right.Key) and
        TEqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(Left.Value, Right.Value);
    end,
    function(const Value: TPair<TKey, TValue>): Integer
    begin
      Result := CombinedHash([
        TEqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.GetHashCode(Value.Key),
        TEqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.GetHashCode(Value.Value)
      ]);
    end
  )
end;
```

I've provided two overloads. If the default comparers for your two types are sufficient, then you can use the parameterless overload. Otherwise you can supply two anonymous methods bespoke to the types.

For your type, you would obtain a comparer like this:

```
TPairComparer.Construct<Int64, Integer>
```

Both of these simple types have default equality comparers that you can use. Hence the parameterless `Construct` overload can be used.

Comment: I agree that complex records need a custom comprarer. For a TPair of two basic value types I expected a bit more support from the compiler or the RTL. I like your solution because it is very generic.

Answer (score 4):

The default comparer for records only works for records of pure value types without padding.  Relying on it, generally, is not a good idea.  For any records which require accurate hashing and equality comparison you really need to write your own comparers.

As has been noted, initializing all of your records with `Default()` is also an option, but this approach is both tedious and error prone - it is easy to forget to initialize a record and it is difficult to trace such an omission when it happens.  The approach is also only effective at eliminating errors related to padding while a custom comparer can also handle reference types, etc.

This, for example, demonstrates a working solution to the problem :

```
program Project1;

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, StrUtils, Generics.Collections, Generics.Defaults,
  System.Hash;

type
  TPairComparer<TKey, TValue> = class(TEqualityComparer<TPair<TKey, TValue>>)
    public
      function Equals(const Left, Right: TPair<TKey, TValue>): Boolean; override;
      function GetHashCode(const Value: TPair<TKey, TValue>): Integer;  override;
  end;
  TInt64IntDict<TValue> = class(TDictionary<TPair<Int64, Integer>, TValue>)
    public constructor Create;
  end;

function TPairComparer<TKey, TValue>.Equals(const Left: TPair<TKey, TValue>;
                                            const Right: TPair<TKey, TValue>) : boolean;
begin
  result := TEqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(Left.Key, Right.Key) and
            TEqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(Left.Value, Right.Value);
end;

{$IFOPT Q+}
  {$DEFINE OVERFLOW_ON}
  {$Q-}
{$ELSE}
  {$UNDEF OVERFLOW_ON}
{$ENDIF}
function TPairComparer<TKey, TValue>.GetHashCode(const Value: TPair<TKey, TValue>) : integer;
begin
  result := THashBobJenkins.GetHashValue(Value.Key, SizeOf(Value.Key), 23 * 31);
  result := THashBobJenkins.GetHashValue(Value.Value, SizeOf(Value.Value), result * 31);
end;
{$IFDEF OVERFLOW_ON}
  {$Q+}
  {$UNDEF OVERFLOW_ON}
{$ENDIF}

constructor TInt64IntDict<TValue>.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(0, TPairComparer<Int64, Integer>.Create);
end;



var
  i1, i2: TPair<Int64, Integer>;
  LI64c : TPairComparer<Int64, Integer>;
  LDict : TInt64IntDict<double>;
begin
  FillMemory(@i1, SizeOf(i1), $00);
  FillMemory(@i2, SizeOf(i1), $01);
  i1.Key := 2;
  i1.Value := -1;
  i2.Key := i1.Key;
  i2.Value := i1.Value;
  WriteLn(Format('i1 key = %d, i1 value = %d', [i1.Key, i1.Value]));
  WriteLn(Format('i2 key = %d, i2 value = %d', [i2.Key, i2.Value]));

  WriteLn; WriteLn('Using Default comparer');
  if TEqualityComparer<TPair<Int64, Integer>>.Default.Equals(i1, i2) then
    WriteLn('i1 equals i2') else WriteLn('i1 not equals i2');
  if TEqualityComparer<TPair<Int64, Integer>>.Default.GetHashCode(i1) =
     TEqualityComparer<TPair<Int64, Integer>>.Default.GetHashCode(i2) then
       WriteLn('i1, i2 - hashes match') else WriteLn('i1, i2 - hashes do not match');

  WriteLn;  WriteLn('Using custom comparer');
  LI64c := TPairComparer<Int64, Integer>.Create;
  if LI64c.Equals(i1, i2) then
    WriteLn('i1 equals i2') else WriteLn('i1 not equals i2');
  if LI64c.GetHashCode(i1) = LI64c.GetHashCode(i2) then
       WriteLn('i1, i2 - hashes match') else WriteLn('i1, i2 - hashes do not match');
  WriteLn;
  LDict := TInt64IntDict<double>.Create;
  LDict.Add(i1, 1.23);
  if LDict.ContainsKey(i2) then
    WriteLn('Dictionary already contains key') else
      WriteLn('Dictionary does not contain key');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

This produces output

> i1 key = 2, i1 value = -1
>   i2 key = 2, i2 value = -1
>
> Using Default comparer
>   i1 not equals i2
>   i1, i2 - hashes do not match
>
> Using custom comparer
>   i1 equals i2
>   i1, i2 - hashes match
>
> Dictionary already contains key

That said, as David's answer demonstrates, using a delegated comparer will produce less overhead and should be favoured in practice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The shortcomings were obvious, I should think.  Like I said, the point wasn't to answer the question of `how can I write combined hash for a generic object`, it was to answer the question of how to knock up the boilerplate for a custom comparer.  Moot point, in any case, it has both now. ;)

Comment: Yeah. I think some of these details are important. And I wanted to show how to do it with Construct which I feel is more concise. Not that any of this is very concise. Would be nice to be able to attach these things to the type in a standard way so that a whole package could be delivered....

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Agreed.  I started here with the aim of condensing this into something short but it's really not possible.  I always use delegated comparers myself, but the answer was getting long already.